# Multiple list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm looking to convert lists like:

```
idx = ['id','m','x','y','z']
a = ['1, 1.0, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11']
b = ['2, 2.0, 2.22, 2.22, 2,22'] 
c = ['3, 3.0, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33']
d = ['4, 4.0, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44'] 
e = ['5, 5.0, 5.55, 5.55, 5.55']
```

Into a dictionary where:

```
dictlist = {
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'm':[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],
    'x':[1.11,2.22,3.33,4.44,5.55],
    'y':[1.11,2.22,3.33,4.44,5.55],
    'z':[1.11,2.22,3.33,4.44,5.55]
}
```

But I would like to be able to do this for a longer set of lists >> 6 elements per list. So I assume a function would be best to be able to create dict for the len of elements in the idx list.

**Edit:
in response to g.d.d.c:

```
I had tried something like:

def make_dict(indx):
    data=dict()
    for item in xrange(0,len(indx)):
        data.update({a[item]:''})
    return data

data = make_dict(idx)
```

Which worked for making:

```
{'id': '', 'm': '', 'x': '', 'y': '', 'z': ''}
```

but then adding each value to the dictionary became an issue.

Comment: Have you made an initial attempt at getting the data structure you want?  Most times you'll get better responses if you show us (non)-working code that comes close so we can improve it, rather than just asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: This could be a one-line comprehension - look into `enumerate()`

Comment: `idx` is a list of 5 strings, while `a`-`e` are each lists containing one string.  Is that correct?

Comment: inspectorG4dget, I am using Python 2.7

Comment: kdopen, That is correct, but you could just do something like newa=a[0].split() to get a new list of separate values.

Comment: How do I ask questions so that I am not detracting from my reputation? I had tried to make the question very general as it then could be helpful to others looking to do a similar task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a single comprehension

Start by grouping your lists {a,b,c,d,e,...} into a list of lists

```
dataset = [a,b,c,d,e]
idx = ['id','m','x','y','z']
d = { k: [v[i] for v in dataset] for i,k in enumerate(idx) }
```

The last line builds a dictionary by enumerating over `idx` using the value for the dict key, and its index to pick out the correct column of each data sample.

The comprehension will work regardless of the number of fields, as long as each list has the same length as `idx`

Comment: Thank you, this works if a,b,c,d,e are lists of multiple values which is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Now what if 

a,b,c,d,e were all one list of a = ['1, 1.0, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11', '2, 2.0, 2.22, 2.22, 2,22','3, 3.0, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33','4, 4.0, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44','5, 5.0, 5.55, 5.55, 5.55']

How would that work?

Comment: That can be done, but it's a different problem you are solving. `dataset = [[ float(i) for i in l.split(",")] for l in a]` would replace the first line

Comment: argh just realized your OP had the values as strings, sorry. think we all missed that. Why are a,b,c,d,e each a list with one element?

Answer (score 2):

```
result = {}
keys = idx
lists = [a, b, c, d, e]
for index, key in enumerate(keys):
    result[key] = []
    for l in lists:
        result[key].append(l[index])
```

Comment: This also (only) works if a,b,c,d,e are lists of multiple values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
idx = ['id','m','x','y','z']
a = [1, 1.0, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11]
b = [2, 2.0, 2.22, 2.22, 2,22] 
c = [3, 3.0, 3.33, 3.33, 3.33]
d = [4, 4.0, 4.44, 4.44, 4.44] 
e = [5, 5.0, 5.55, 5.55, 5.55]


dictlist =  {x[0] : list(x[1:]) for x in zip(idx,a,b,c,d,e)}

print dictlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = {}
for key, a,b,c,d,e in zip(idx, map(lambda s:[float(i) for i in s.split(',')], [a,b,c,d,e])):
    answer[key] = [a,b,c,d,e]
```